# Use Shiny App with selectInput and calculations based on each unique value in a column to output new table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a big data set that has about 50 variables and about 40 unique companies in one of the columns.

The work I need to do with the data is basically to find out how many NA's are there in each column for each company.

My code looks like this, and my problem now is how do I use my second selectInput to display `low_check` table when I choose "Table_1" and display `high_check` table when I choose "Table_2"?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

headerPanel("Report"),

sidebarPanel(
           selectInput(inputId = "carriers", label = "Choose a company:", 
           choices = unique(T1Q3_std$CARRIER)),
           selectInput(inputId = "table", label = "Table #:", 
           choices = c("Table_1", "Table_2")
)


),
      mainPanel(

  tableOutput("table1"),
  tableOutput("table2")
            )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

low_check <- reactive({

    low_index_T1 <- c("T1.3", "T1.4", "T1.5", "T1.6", "T1.7 and T1.9", "T1.8", "T1.10",
       "T1.11", "T1.12")

    low_data_element_T1 <- c("element1", " element2",
                  "element3", "element4", "element5",
                  "element6", "element7", "element8", "element9")


    low_issue_T1 <- c("issue1", "issue2", "issue3", "issue4",
           "issue5", "issue6", "issue7", "issue8", "issue9")

    T1.3 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element1", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.4 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element2", funs(sum(is.na(.))))


    T1.5 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element3", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.6 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element4", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.7 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element5", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.8 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element6", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.10 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element7", funs(sum(is.na(.))))
    count()

    T1.11 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element8", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.12 <- T1Q3_std %>%
    filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
    summarise_at("element9", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    low_num_of_violations_T1 <- as.integer(c(T1.3, T1.4, T1.5, T1.6,
                           T1.7, T1.8, T1.10, T1.11, T1.12))

    low_priority_check_T1 <- tibble(Index = low_index_T1, "Data Element" = low_data_element_T1,
                                    Issue = low_issue_T1, "# of Violations" = low_num_of_violations_T1)


})
high_check <- reactive({

    high_index_T1 <- c("T1.14", "T1.15", "T1.16", "T1.22")


    high_data_element_T1 <- c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4")



    high_issue_T1 <- c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4")

    T1.14 <- T1Q3_std %>%
                filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
                summarise_at("e1", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.15 <- T1Q3_std %>%
            filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
            summarise_at("e2", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.16 <- T1Q3_std %>%
            filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
            summarise_at("e3", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    T1.22 <- T1Q3_std %>%
            filter(CARRIER == input$carriers) %>%
            summarise_at("e4", funs(sum(is.na(.))))

    high_num_of_violations_T1 <- as.integer(c(T1.14, T1.15, T1.16, T1.22))


    high_priority_check_T1 <- tibble(Index = high_index_T1, "Data Element" = high_data_element_T1,
                                  Issue = high_issue_T1, "# of Violations" = high_num_of_violations_T1)

})
output$table1 <- renderTable({
    low_check()
})
output$table2 <- renderTable({
    high_check()
})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, you could write a shiny app that would do that.

Comment: Hi, May I ask what would be the main commands I need in the server part of the app?

Comment: This question is not detailed enough for anyone to give you a suggestion, what you will need to do is create a reproducible example with some of your input data, ui design, expected output, and what you have tried so far. Also try to narrow down your question as you are working. I think we can figure this one out if you could that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and I am truly sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `conditionalPanel` like this:

```
mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.table == 'Table_1'", tableOutput("table1")
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.table == 'Table_2'", tableOutput("table2")
      )
)
```

Edit:

To show multiple outputs:

```
mainPanel(
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.table == 'Table_1'", 
            tableOutput("table1"), 
            tableOutput("table1new") # and so on....
          ),
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.table == 'Table_2'", tableOutput("table2")
          )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I wanted. But also is it possible to display more than 1 tables under one condition? For example, under condition input.table == 'Table_1', can I display 2 tables instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just add it as another `tableOutput`. See edited answer.

Comment: Hi, just a little additional question. How could I set the download button to download the table(s) that is displaying.